# How to increase the size of "SlugField()" with "unique=True" in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, unique-constraint, slug

I need to increase size of my slug to 500 which by default is 255 characters and at the same time, I need to keep it unique as well. Is there a way around to make it happen?

models.py:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    sku = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
    url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
```

Please advise.

Comment: What happens if/when you do `slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=500)`?

Comment: @Rexford depends on the backend - most of the time data will be capped at 255

Comment: Are you using migrations ??

Comment: If the backend is mysql, [Django DB doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#character-fields) tells you the max_length is limited to 255 if unique is True.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/databases/#character-fields) the maximum length for a `SlugField` is 255 characters. But it is the database backend that enforces it so, depending on which backend you are using, you *might* be able to increase that.

SQLite and PostgreSQL both allow `max_length` to be set to 500 with a `UNIQUE` constraint. Note that PostgreSQL will actually enforce the length limit, whereas SQLite doesn't really care and will allow you to insert strings greater than the declared size.

But the MySQL/Mariadb driver will enforce the 255 character limit in `django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py`. Within the standard backends, this is the only one that has this restriction. The 255 comes from the restriction that the maximum index key for a InnoDB column is 767 bytes. If you store UTF8 data in the column, as you must, it can take up to 3 bytes per character, which results in 767/3 = 255 characters.

One possible solution is to have an additional `CharField` containing a hash of the slug. That field will be short (e.g. 32 bytes for MD5 digest) *and* it will be unique which will stop duplicate slugs being inserted. Population of the slug and its hash can be done in `Product.save()`.

The model will be:

```
import hashlib
from django.utils.text import slugify

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    sku = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
    url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=500)
    slug_hash = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        self.slug_hash = hashlib.md5(self.slug).hexdigest()
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now if an attempt to save a record with the same slug is attempted an `IntegrityError` on the `slug_hash` will be raised.

Comment: What if i add unique True to slug field? How can i raise error when form is submitted and slug turns out to already exist?

Comment: You can add the unique constraint to a `SlugField`, but then you are limited to 255 characters. Attempting to save a record with a duplicate slug will cause `IntegrityError` to be raised.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I came up with a solution, but not sure its any good. I would greatly appreciate if you can have a look at it, if you are okay with this? And if you are, where should i post my code?  I am now hijacking someone else his topic, i really shouldn't.

Comment: @stetim94: no need to hijack this question, you can simply post a new question. If you're looking for a critique of your code then you should consider posting on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Post your question here if you have problems with your code, and include minimal sample code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you have a look? Its just 10 lines of code: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/154564/raising-an-error-for-slug-unique-in-django

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible using signals. The slug field will automatically get created/updated before saving the instance of the model. To make it unique you can concatenate the title with the id if a model instance with same slug already exists. See code bellow (add it to your model) :

```
def create_slug(instance, new_slug=None):
    """
    A function to create a slug
    if an object with slug already exists, it adds id value to slug
    else  just slugify the title
    """
    slug = slugify(instance.title)
    if new_slug is not None:
        slug = new_slug
    qs = Product.objects.filter(slug=slug).order_by('-id')
    exists = qs.exists()
    if exists:
        new_slug = "%s-%s" %(slug, qs.first().id)
        return create_slug(instance, new_slug=new_slug) #recursive call 
    return slug

def pre_save_product_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    A signal that calls the function create_slug if an object has not slug 
    """
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = create_slug(instance)

pre_save.connect(pre_save_product_receiver, sender=Product)
```

To increase slug max characters replace your field with this :

```
slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 255, unique=True)
```

Don't go over 255 to avoid trouble in case you change your database technology.

Answer (score 0):

Using **PostgreSQL** and **SQLite**, I could set `max_length=500` with `unique=True` to [SlugField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) as shown below, then I could save `500` characters in Django Admin according to my experiments:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model): # ↓ Here ↓
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=500, unique=True)
```